# How can I convert a JSON object from a HashMap<String, Object> into a MultivaluedMap<String, String>?

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have a java object that is a HashMap<String, Object> that I'm using to store JSON data.

```
public class Foo{
    private HashMap<String, Object> protocall;

    public HashMap<String, Object> getProtocall() {
        return protocall;
    }
}
```

This is an example of the JSON being stored

```
{
    "protocall": {
        "A": "hello",
        "B": "world",
        "paramaters": {
            "StartDate": [
                "09-01-2000 00:00:00.000"
            ],
            "EndDate": [
                "09-01-2021 00:00:00.000"
            ],
            "Name": [
                "Logan"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However, I need to insert the parameters object into a MultivalueMap<String, String>, but using the method

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
MultivaluedMap<String, String> paramaters = (MultivaluedMap<String, String>)bar.getProtocall().get("paramaters");
```

does not work. Is there a way to build a multivalued map using the parameters object?

Comment: What library are you using to read/write the json file?

Comment: I'm actually using hibernate to get varbinary data from a SQL database